# Variable me aparece nula en el metodo, pero deberia tener valor

Tags: c#

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections;

namespace BootstrapTemplate
{
    public class SQL_Connection
    {
        private string NamereportSeleccionado;
        private string IDreporteSeleccionado;

        public void getInfoReporteseleccionado(string nombre, string id)
        {
            this.NamereportSeleccionado = nombre;
            this.IDreporteSeleccionado = id;
        }
```

En el metodo getInfoReporteseleccionado llegan dos datos, se asigna a las variables NamereportSeleccionado e IDreporteSeleccionado, y al correrlo con breakpoints puedo ver que tienen los valores que corresponden

El problema es que mas adelante cuando tengo que usar una de las variables, el valor de esta llega como nula (en la linea de string query hasta el final)

```
 public DataTable SQL_Leer_TablaReporteSeleccionado()
        {
            DataTable TablaReporteSeleccionado = new DataTable();
            string query = "  select  P.NombreProducto, DP.DemandaSemanal, DP.DemandaMensual, DP.Rate1,DP.Rate2,DP.SalidaDiaria,DP.DiasRequeridos,DP.Turnos,DP.HCTurno  FROM DatoProducto DP, Producto P WHERE P.IDProducto=DP.IDProducto and IDReporte=" + IDreporteSeleccionado;
            string con = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQL_Connection_String"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection SQLCon = new SqlConnection(con))
            {
                SQLCon.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = SQLCon.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                adapter.Fill(TablaReporteSeleccionado);
                SQLCon.Close();
            }
            return TablaReporteSeleccionado;
        }
```

Alguna idea de que pueda ser, ya he usado ese codigo en otro programa y si me funciona no se por que ahora no.
Gracias espero su ayuda.

Comment: falta contexto para saber que pasa.. esos dos metodos estan en la misma clase?

Comment: Pon la declaracion completa de tu clase

Comment: Si estan en la misma clase

Comment: Te sugiero que agregues la clase completa.

Comment: verifica si el metodo SQL_Leer_TablaReporteSeleccionado no se esta mandando a llamar antes de que se le asigne el valor a la variable IDreporteSeleccionado